# Synapse Pipeline: dynamically assign parameter values from a config file or table

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-synapse

TLDR;

Is there a way to assign synapse pipeline/activity parameter values (such as source/destination folder names etc.) dynamically i.e. reading through a config file or table instead of manually specifying the same?

[image: parameters]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

I have a Synapse pipeline that has a Notebook Activity performing some transformation and copying tasks. I am passing the source and destination folders and some other parameters to the notebook through activity/pipeline parameters. However, instead of hardcoding these parameter values, I would like to define these values in a file (or a table) and then read the values from there, so I can have one source of truth for all my pipelines which will use the same parameters and also make the solution portable across different environments, without needing to modify each pipeline. Is there an expression or function that would allow me to add such dynamic content?

My current solution is to define a YAML config file and add the path to this config file in each of my pipelines so it can read those values from there. But I was wondering if there is more elegant way to do it.
Another options seems to be using a lookup activity but it is bit involved and require setting up control tables and writing queries etc. ???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign values to parameters dynamically, you can follow the procedure below:

Create a table in the database with ParameterName and ParameterValue columns using the code below:

```
create table parameters(ParameterName varchar(20), ParameterValue varchar(20))
insert into parameters(ParameterName, ParameterValue) values('src_root', 'AA')
```

Create a linked service for the database and a dataset with the linked service. Drag the Look up activity, select the dataset as the source, and select the Query option. Use the query below:

```
select ParameterValue from parameters where ParameterName = 'src_root'
```

[image]

Use the dynamic expression below to assign the value to the parameter:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].ParameterValue
```

[image]

The expression will give the output as shown below:

[image]